# Popup-окно с компонентом в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, popup

Нужно вывести popup-окно с формой для отправки сообщения по клику в главном меню.
Только начинаю изучать Битрикс, хотелось бы понять, как все это сделать правильно?

Я так понимаю, нужно создать инфоблок, где будут поля для сообщения и загрузки файла, которые будут инициализироваться через админку, где и можно будет редактировать e-mail, на который будет все это отправляться.

Нужно создать страницу, куда вставить код инфоблока, которая будет вызываться в контексте popup.

Структурно, вроде, ясно (если не так, поправьте, пожалуйста), а как реализовать на деле?

Спасибо!

Comment: Инфоблоки не при чём. В битриксе есть отдельный компонент - веб-формы: создаёте там новую форму (вопросы, варианты ответов, шаблон и т.д.), в popup через код вызова компонента подключаете созданную форму. Чтобы куда-то что-то отправлялось, нужно подключить к форме почтовое событие. Это если очень коротко :) Подробнее читайте документацию: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?CHAPTER_ID=742&COURSE_ID=41

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Comment: А почему не вызывается повторно попап? Нужно страницу ребутить, чтобы снова появилась возможность вызвать попап-окно по клику.

Comment: Сергей, я ж не знаю, как именно Вы вызываете popup ) С битриксом реализация вызова popup никак не связана.

Comment: popup у меня запускается в хедере

Comment: var popup = new BX.CDialog({
            'title': '',
            'content_url': '/path/index.php',
            'height': '700px',
            'draggable': true,
            'resizable': true,
        });

Comment: хм... не могу Вам подсказать, с таким не работал никогда. обычно пользуюсь модальными окнами бутстрапа или чем-то самописным

Answer (score 2):

для небольших сайтов часто покупается редакция старт, у которой нет модуля "веб формы"

если делать запись данных с форм в инфоблоки:

1. делаем форму
2. создаем скрипт приема сообщений, например, в /local/app/form.php

form.php будет иметь следующее содержание

```
# отключаем не нужный функционал для ajax запроса
define("STOP_STATISTICS", true);
define('NO_AGENT_CHECK', true);
define("STATISTIC_SKIP_ACTIVITY_CHECK", true);

# подключаем bitrix
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

$errors = array();
$data = array();

$request = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getContext()->getRequest();

# валидация значений из $request

if(!$request->get('phone'))
   $errors['phone'] = 'Не введен номер телефона';

...  и т.д.

if(!\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('iblock'))
   $errors['total'] = 'системная ошибка';

if(empty($errors))
{
   # добавление в базу 
   #https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/index.php
   $el = new CIBlockElement;

   $PROP = array();
   $PROP['PHONE'] = $request->get('phone')

   $arLoadProductArray = Array(
     "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
     "IBLOCK_ID"      => # ваш IBLOCK_ID,
     "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,
     "NAME"           => "Запрос",
     "ACTIVE"         => "N",
     "DETAIL_TEXT"    => $request->get('message')
     );

     if($PRODUCT_ID = $el->Add($arLoadProductArray))
        $data['id'] = $PRODUCT_ID;
     else
        $errors['total'] = $el->LAST_ERROR;
}

if(!empty($errors))
{
    # при наличии ошибки возвращаем 422 для обработки в о 
    header('Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity');
    echo Bitrix\Main\Web\Json::encode($errors, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
else
{
    echo Bitrix\Main\Web\Json::encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    # или echo json_encode($data);
}
```

в js скрипте (для примера возьмем jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
   ... параметры 
  success: function(){
     // код для ответа со статусом 200
     // показываем блок "запрос принят" и скрываем форму
  },
  error: function(responce){
    // вернулась 422 ошибка
    // перебрать массив из ответа, 
    // и т.к. мы задавали ошибкам ключи
    // можно добавить класс ошибок к полям по ключу массива
  }
})
```

P.S. для стандартизации ответов в Битрикс для ajax запросов написал свой класс, может пригодится
https://github.com/domatskiy/bitrix-ajax-response